# JS Combine an Object based on the same criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello fellow coders & kindred spirits,

each time a user clicks on a basket to add a product an object is created that is named:
field_x
where x is always + 1 starting from 1.

My goal is to create a function that checks if there is the same item already present multiple times and if yes then it should 
take all the piece values, combine them together, substitute the piece value of the first item with this new number and delete all the
other matching arrays.

Here is a stringified example of what I have in mind:

Input:

- field_1
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_2
  [{"name":"B","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_3
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_4
  [{"name":"C","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_5
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_6
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_7
  [{"name":"B","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_8
  [{"name":"C","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_9
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]
- field_10
  [{"name":"A","piece":1,"active":"true"}]

Output:

- field_1
  [{"name":"A","piece":6,"active":"true"}]
- field_2
  [{"name":"B","piece":2,"active":"true"}]
- field_3
  [{"name":"C","piece":2,"active":"true"}]

I should note that eval is not planned to be used in the final version.
I know it is not a good idea to use it and I know how to substitute it.

The code I have so far does not provide me with a solution and I do not know what to do next.

```
<script src="js/underscore.js"></script>

<script>
var fieldsNumber = 10;

var field_1 = new Array();
var field_2 = new Array();

var field_3 = new Array();
var field_4 = new Array();

var field_5 = new Array();
var field_6 = new Array();

var field_7 = new Array();
var field_8 = new Array();

var field_9 = new Array();
var field_10 = new Array();

var tempField01 = new Array();
var tempField02 = new Array();

var tempField03 = new Array();
var tempField04 = new Array();

field_1.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});
field_2.push({
    name: 'B',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});

field_3.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});
field_4.push({
    name: 'C',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});

field_5.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});
field_6.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});

field_7.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});
field_8.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});

field_9.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});
field_10.push({
    name: 'A',
    piece: 1,
    active: 'true'
});


var jSorageItemContents = new Array();

//HEADER START
for (var i = 1; i < fieldsNumber + 1; i++) {

    console.log("======================");
    console.log("field_" + i);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(eval("field_" + i)));

} //HEADER END



console.log("======================");
console.log("----------------------");

for (var i = 1; i < fieldsNumber + 1; i++) {

    console.log(i);


    for (var n = 1; n < fieldsNumber + 1; n++) {

        var tempField01 = eval("field_" + i);
        var tempField02 = eval("field_" + n);


        var docA = _.omit(tempField01, ['price']);
        var docB = _.omit(tempField02, ['price']);

        //  console.log("-----------------");
        //  console.log('docA');
        //  console.log(JSON.stringify(docA));
        //
        //  console.log('tempField02');
        //  console.log(JSON.stringify(docB));
        //
        //  console.log("-----------------");


        if (docA[0].done == 'true' || docB[0].done == 'true') {

        } else {



            if (Object.is(JSON.stringify(docA), JSON.stringify(docB))) {


                //  console.log("field_" + i + " and field_" + n + " do match!");
                //  console.log('Lets Rock and Roll');




                //  console.log("field_" + i + "[0].piece");
                //  console.log(eval("field_" + i + "[0]['piece']"));
                var kusA = parseInt(eval("field_" + i + "[0]['piece']"), 10);
                var kusB = parseInt(eval("field_" + n + "[0]['piece']"), 10);

                var noveKusy = kusA + kusB;
                var nula = 0;

                eval("field_" + i + "[0]['piece'] = " + noveKusy);

                eval("field_" + i + "[0]['done'] = true");
                eval("field_" + n + "[0]['done'] = true");
                eval("field_" + n + "[0]['active'] = false");



            } else {

                //   console.log("field_" + i + " sa s field_" + n + " do not match");

            }
        }
    }
    //  }
}

console.log("======================");
console.log("======================");
console.log("======================");


//FOOTER START
for (var i = 1; i < fieldsNumber + 1; i++) {

    console.log("======================");
    console.log("field_" + i);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(eval("field_" + i)));

} //FOOTER END
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: just a hint, you could use an array for holding all `fields` and you could easily process them in a loop.

Comment: Is it a requirement that a `field_xx` object is created on each basket click? Why is it an array, when it always will have one element? Why don't you just use one array or nested object?

Comment: well.. client requests that it acts like that.. they export the data to the Excel later on and it is not my part of job to edit that process so.. yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a better structure for the collecting parts in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Then you can iterate over the array with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and group the parts.

```js
var data = [{ name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "B", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "C", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "B", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "C", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }, { name: "A", piece: 1, active: "true" }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, piece: 0, active: a.active };
        grouped.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    this[a.name].piece += a.piece;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For an even better structure, i suggest to use an object, with name as key and get an easy access to the count and other data of the item, like

> ```
> var items = {
>     A: {
>         name: "A",
>         piece: 1,
>         active: "true"
>     },
>     B: {
>         name: "B",
>         piece: 1,
>         active: "true"
>     },
>     C: {
>         name: "C",
>         piece: 1,
>         active: "true"
>     }
> };
> ```

Edit, key with multiple parameters

```js
var dataToProcess = [{ "row": 4, "col": 3, "kg_m": "1.36", "m_t": "735", "v_d": 5000, "selectedTransection": "rectangle", "dCellText": "30x20", "mmCellText": "2", "active": "true", "piece": 1 }, { "row": 4, "col": 3, "kg_m": "1.36", "m_t": "735", "v_d": 6000, "selectedTransection": "rectangle", "dCellText": "30x20", "mmCellText": "2", "active": "true", "piece": 1 }, { "row": 4, "col": 3, "kg_m": "1.92", "m_t": "521", "v_d": 5000, "selectedTransection": "circle", "dCellText": "33.7", "mmCellText": "2.5", "active": "true", "piece": 1 }, { "row": 5, "col": 1, "kg_m": "1.78", "m_t": "562", "v_d": 6000, "selectedTransection": "circle", "dCellText": "38", "mmCellText": "2", "active": "true", "piece": 20 }, { "row": 5, "col": 1, "kg_m": "1.78", "m_t": "562", "v_d": 6000, "selectedTransection": "circle", "dCellText": "38", "mmCellText": "2", "active": "true", "piece": 1 }],
    dataProcessed = [];

dataToProcess.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = [a.name, a.col, a.kg_m, a.m_t, a.v_d, a.selectedTransection, a.dCellText, a.mmCellText].join('|');
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = {
            row: a.row,
            col: a.col,
            kg_m: a.kg_m,
            m_t: a.m_t,
            v_d: a.v_d,
            selectedTransection: a.selectedTransection,
            dCellText: a.dCellText,
            mmCellText: a.mmCellText,
            active: a.active,
            piece: 0
        };
        dataProcessed.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].piece += a.piece;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(dataProcessed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.Well, I will need to breake it up to an array structure like one I have mentioned in the question since client needs that to behave that way. They store the information in a separate fields using jStorage library. The suggestion provided is helpful, working as expected. I thank you for that. I think I will just add a function to breake it down at the end again and it will work like they need it to.

Comment: I have been trying to use your answer in a real world scenario but I just do not understand what is happening 6th row of your answer. The real world scenario uses an array for each basket number that looks like this:

 "row": 4,
 "col": 3,
 "kg_m": "1.36",
 "m_t": "735",
 "v_d": 5000,
 "selectedTransection": "rectangle",
 "dCellText": "30x20",
 "mmCellText": "2",
 "active": "true",
 "piece": 1

how can I incorporate this fact into solution provided by you? I have tried many things but I just can't find a way :/

Comment: I had to use the name A, B, C scenario for client has requested not to use the real key names for "security purposes" but once I have acknowledged them that I have to provide them for you to better understand the question, they have approved. Sorry for the double time it will take if you will decide to help me further with this. I appreciate every help provided.

Comment: if you mean the assignment line of the object, you could use this `this[a.name] = { row: a.row, col: a.col, kg_m: a.kg_m, m_t: a.m_t, v_d: a.v_d, selectedTransection: a.selectedTransection, dCellText: a.dCellText, mmCellText: a.mmCellText, active: a.active, piece: 0 };` qhich basically copies all properties and uses for piece a zero for the count. if you have more questions, you are welcome.

Comment: Ok so what I have right now is this and it does not change the output at all: 
dataToProcess.forEach(function(a) {
    if (!this[a.name] || !this[a.col] || !this[a.kg_m] || !this[a.m_t] || !this[a.v_d] || !this[a.selectedTransection] || !this[a.dCellText] || !this[a.mmCellText]) {
        this[a.name] = {row: a.row, col: a.col, kg_m: a.kg_m, m_t: a.m_t, v_d: a.v_d, selectedTransection: a.selectedTransection, dCellText: a.dCellText, mmCellText: a.mmCellText, active: a.active, piece: 0};
dataProcessed.push(this[a.name]);}
    this[a.name].piece += a.name;
}, Object.create(null));

Comment: you need only `if(!this[a.name]) {` not the rest. or something with a unique value, like an id.

Comment: still not working, take a look at this.. what am I missing? http://pastebin.com/FReaQ0qP

Comment: what is the unique parameter of th data to group on?

Comment: can you start chat with me? I would like to respond you but I can't open it since my rep is low

Comment: yes i can, but not actually. i could give you a ping later.

Comment: ok, great! i just want to send you the link to answer your question, that is all. But in general: all the parameters should be unique. If there is only one difference in any of the parameters, it should not group those together. If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: i think, you could use a key with all parameters you need for a unique count. https://jsfiddle.net/shcko4v1/